# Entity Framework Core extract .Equals-combination method for several Entity objects with same fields

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core with .NET Core 3.1.

I have several entities that all have Integer-Columns for

- IsDeleted and
- IsActive.

So in my code you can find quite often things like

```
return DbContext.Organization.Single(w => w.Identifier.Equals(identifier) && w.Isactive.Equals(1) && w.Isdeleted.Equals(0));
```

or

```
return DbContext.Product.Single(w => w.Identifier.Equals(identifier) && w.Isactive.Equals(1) && w.Isdeleted.Equals(0));
```

I want to extract a method for this part:

```
w.Isactive.Equals(1) && w.Isdeleted.Equals(0)
```

Maybe it is because of Friday, but I don't get it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should look into Entity Framework Query Filters.

Comment: For readability I wouldn't change it. you will essentially be changing `w.Isactive.Equals(1) && w.Isdeleted.Equals(0)` to  something like `isValid(w)`

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă - I actually chosed to work with query filters. Best solution as it is very present to have that active/deleted combination in the software. Thank you, buddy.

Comment: @Neil - If you name it IsActiveAndNotDeleted() I think that's even mehr readable than using .Equals(1) and .Equals(0).

Comment: @iquellis I agree. That is why I said for readability I wouldn't change it. Hope you find a good solution though. That being said the answer Amel gave looks promising

Answer (score 1):

**BEAUTIFUL, CLEAN AND SEXY WAY (USING QUERY FILTERS)**

In this case to add a method that would apply that filter on all entities which contain these two properties. Bear in mind that you should distinct those with some interface or a base class so every implementation of that interface will have this filter applied.

**Note: I'm sure this will compile, but I'm not sure if this filter will be applied correcty, it was a long time since I was using Expressions in this way. Give it a try, it's a recommended way without too much refactoring**

For example, create an interface:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

and in the implementation:

```
public class Product : ISomething
{
    // Implementation
}

public class Organization : ISomething
{
    // Implementation
}
```

Then in your DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ApplyQueryFilter(modelBuilder);
    ...
```

And to implement this method:

```
private void ApplyQueryFilter(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.EntitiesOfType<ISomething>(builder =>
    {
        builder.Property<bool>(nameof(ISomething.IsDeleted)).HasDefaultValue(false);
        builder.Property<bool>(nameof(ISomething.IsActive)).HasDefaultValue(true);
 
        var param = Expression.Parameter(builder.Metadata.ClrType, "p");
        var isDeletableExpression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, nameof(ISomething.IsDeleted)), Expression.Constant(false));
        var isActiveExpression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, nameof(ISomething.IsActive)), Expression.Constant(true));
 
        Expression isDeletableIsActive = Expression.AndAlso(isDeletableExpression, isActiveExpression);
 
        builder.HasQueryFilter(Expression.Lambda(isDeletableIsActive, param));
    });
}
```

In this case, you will have this filter applied to all entities which implement ISomething interface.

**DON'T CARE WAY**

Create a base class, add a method which will return that expression, and make all those entities inherit from the base class.

Base class:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Method:

```
private Expression<Func<BaseEntity, bool>> ActiveNotDeleted()
{
    return x => x.IsActive == true && x.IsDeleted == false;
}
```

Comment: Deleted my solution as it was just compiling, but not working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually I chosed to solve the challenge with filters, because the active/deleted combination is very present in that software and in 95% of the cases what you want.

Comment: Glad to help :)